# vb.net for each loop that compares a row to every other row

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to format some datagridview rows based on comparing them with other rows.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DaisyServicesForm.DataGridView1.Rows

        If row.Cells("UnitCost").Value = row.Cells("UnitCost").Value And (row.Cells("FromDate").Value <= row.Cells("ToDate").Value And row.Cells("ToDate").Value >= row.Cells("FromDate").Value) Then
            row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue
        End If
    Next
```

But I don't want VB to compare rows to themselves, I want it to take first row and then compare it with every other row...and then take the second row and compare that with ever other row.

If it was in SQL it would look something like:

```
i.unitcost = i2.unitcost
and ((i.FromDate <= i2.ToDate)  
and  (i.ToDate >= i2.FromDate))
```

Hope that makes sense, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong, but if you reach your goal then you will see a lot of blue here.

Comment: There are some other conditions, this is just example code.

Comment: It seems like you need a second For loop within this one. But I'm concerned that if you compare your rows to other rows (perhaps one you already changed) you may find some other issues. What's your goal here? You might want to just compare the datasource only.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the goal is to highlight the rows on the datagridview, where there are overlapping ranges. So for example it a.FieldA = b.FieldA and a.FieldB = b.FieldB AND the date ranges overlap, so a.FromDate <= b.ToDate)  and  a.ToDate >= b.FromDate then hightlight both those rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an inner `For Loop` if you want to have each item (row) iterated through and compare itself vs every other item in the list (grid).

```
For Each rowOuter As DataGridViewRow In DaisyServicesForm.DataGridView1.Rows
    For Each rowInner As DataGridViewRow In DaisyServicesForm.DataGridView1.Rows
        If rowOuter.Cells("UnitCost").Value = rowInner.Cells("UnitCost").Value And 
            (rowOuter.Cells("FromDate").Value <= rowInner.Cells("ToDate").Value And rowOuter.Cells("ToDate").Value >= rowInner.Cells("FromDate").Value) Then
            rowOuter.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue
    End If
    Next
Next
```

- The first outer row will compare itself to all rows.
- The next outer row will compare itself to to all rows.
- ...
- The final row will compare itself to all rows.

You probably need to check the if statement I have there, but the idea should work. Also, you need to add a check so see if it the row is checking itself.