# how to compare one datagridview all rows index to other datagridview all rows index in Vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I'm not good at programming and I recently got a task to do at my internship in which I have to compare one Excel File with another Excel file using Vb.net. I've made the form one in which I can select two different Excel files [Image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsh4Y.jpg) By clicking the view data button a new form is open to show data in data grid view same case with second file [Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIqyG.jpg) . All I want to do now is compare cell(0)(5)(6) of all rows only from datagridview of first file with the same cells of all rows of datagridview of the second file and show the difference of cell(5) and cell(6) in a new datagridview on another form.
I know that nested for loop will be required for that which will check the first row cell(0) with the second file first row cell(0) and if they are same then it will give difference of the cell(5)(6) in the result form if not then it will check the first row cell(0) of first file with the second row cell(0) with the second file. Please help me with this code because I'm not good with loops.
Here is the code

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Start_Up
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Dim nTemp As Integer
    Dim sMsg As String
    sMsg = "Are you sure you want to exit the program?"
    nTemp = MessageBox.Show(sMsg, "Confirm Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    If nTemp = DialogResult.Yes Then
        Application.Exit()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    File_1.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    File_2.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection
    Dim dta As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dts As DataSet
    Dim excel As String
    Dim openfiledialog As New OpenFileDialog

    openfiledialog.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
    openfiledialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Excel Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx| CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv| XLS Files (*.xls)|*xls)"

    If (openfiledialog.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        Dim fi As New FileInfo(openfiledialog.FileName)
        Dim filename As String = openfiledialog.FileName
        TextBox1.Text = fi.ToString
        excel = fi.FullName
        conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From[ITR$]", conn)
        dts = New DataSet
        dta.Fill(dts, "[ITR$]")
        File_1.DataGridView1.DataSource = dts
        File_1.DataGridView1.DataMember = "[ITR$]"

        conn.Close()
        If TextBox1.Text = fi.ToString Then
            CheckBox1.Checked = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection
    Dim dta As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dts As DataSet
    Dim excel As String
    Dim openfiledialog As New OpenFileDialog

    openfiledialog.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
    openfiledialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Excel Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx| CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv| XLS Files (*.xls)|*xls)"

    If (openfiledialog.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        Dim fi As New FileInfo(openfiledialog.FileName)
        Dim filename As String = openfiledialog.FileName
        TextBox2.Text = fi.ToString
        excel = fi.FullName
        conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From[ITR$]", conn)
        dts = New DataSet
        dta.Fill(dts, "[ITR$]")
        File_2.DataGridView1.DataSource = dts
        File_2.DataGridView1.DataMember = "[ITR$]"

        conn.Close()
        If TextBox2.Text = fi.ToString Then
            CheckBox2.Checked = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub CompButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   CompButton.Click
    'For progressbar on click of compare button (Starts)
    ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = 0
    Timer1.Start()
    CompButton.Enabled = False
    'For ProgressBar(End)
    If File_1.DataGridView1.RowCount() - 1 = File_2.DataGridView1.RowCount() - 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("No New Entries Have Been Done or Removed", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Some New Entries Have Been Done or Removed", "New Entries", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)

    End If
   '(THE LOOP WILL BE HERE)
    End Sub
```

Please help me with this code thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985535/vb-net-for-each-loop-that-compares-a-row-to-every-other-row). It has already been answered here. You can replace the "UnitCost" or "FromDate" with the index of your required cells.

Comment: thanks @Leprechaun I've read that post before asking this question here but in it if the conditions are true it will only change the color but what I wanted to do is to check the cells(0) of first file with second file cell(0) and if they are same then it will subtract the cell(5) and cell(6) value of both files and show the result with the name on third form in another datagridview because the first cell contains names and cell (5)(6) contain numbers. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each rowDGV1 As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

    For Each rowDGV2 As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows

        If (rowDGV1.Cells(0).Value = rowDGV2.Cells(0).Value) And 
           (rowDGV1.Cells(5).Value = rowDGV2.Cells(5).Value) And
           (rowDGV1.Cells(6).Value = rowDGV2.Cells(6).Value) Then _
            AddRow(rowDGV1.Cells(0).Value, _
                   rowDGV1.Cells(5).Value, _
                   rowDGV1.Cells(6).Value)

    Next

Next


Private Sub AddRow(ByVal strName as String, ByVal strOne as String, ByVal strTwo as String)
    'Add a row into the 3rd dgv with the values presuming you have already added columns in it (for name and difference)

    Dim strValue as String = Cdbl(strOne) - Cdbl(strTwo)
    dgv3.Rows.Add()
    dgv3.Item(dgcName, dgv3.RowCount - 1).Value = strName
    dgv3.Item(dgcDifference,dgv3.RowCount - 1) = strValue
    dgv3.Item(dgcDGV1Col5,dgv3.RowCount - 1) = strOne
    dgv3.Item(dgcDGV1Col6,dgv3.RowCount - 1) = strTwo
    dgv3.Item(dgcDGV2Col5,dgv3.RowCount - 1) = strOne
    dgv3.Item(dgcDGV2Col6,dgv3.RowCount - 1) = strOne

End Sub
```

May be this can work.

Comment: Thanks @Leprechaun this helped me understand a little bit but due to some changes in program now I'm stuck at one last place if you can help me with the code. I everything is fine I've made a module in which I can compare two columns but now I just want to do is that I want to show DGV1 column(0) DGV1 col(5) and (6) as well as DGV2 col(5) and (6) in the third DGV3.

Comment: I made an edit to the code, but columns 5 and 6 are the same anyway so essentially you are repeating the information. is this really what you want?

Comment: thanks @leprechaun the code is fine but still need some working because I'm getting runtime errors as soon as I'll complete it or need help I'll let you know.